# Wordpress members-only page with link visible only to members

Tags: user-registration

How to achieve Wordpress members-only page functionality with a link in the primary menu visible only to members?

Is there a plug-in for that? The Wordpress version is 3.2.1. It is self hosted.

Comment: Is this for wordpress.com or a self-hosted WordPress installation?

Comment: @Al Sorry, it is self-hosted. I added the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-access-control/ seems to do what you need. You can probably also use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/ but it's sort of complicated.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you very much!